# Redirect using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-302

I want to redirect all user page requests to a page on the same domain.

For example, I have an "under construction, BRB" page that I want all users to see when they try to access ANY page on the site.

I tried using this:

```
Redirect 302 / http://www.domain.com/index2.php
```

What that does is try to apply the redirect to the index2.php page as well and it gets stuck in a loop where the user then sees this until the browser stops.

```
http://www.domain.com/index2.phpindex2.phpindex2.phpindex2.php etc., etc,
```

Any idea on how to write that rule to except that page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to exclude the file you want to redirect to. Here’s an example with mod_rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule !^index2\.php$ /index2.php [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I'm probably doing it wrong but my broswer is returning "Too many redirects" errors when I try this.

Comment: How would I write this so it wouldn't rewrite the CSS files required to display the page correctly?

Comment: No need to specify the 302 return, mod_rewrite will do that by default.

Comment: @Tom: Add a RewriteCond directive to explude additional URI paths: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(css|images|foobar)/`.

Comment: I think we're getting there but when I add that, the redirecting stops working....
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(_assets)/
    RewriteRule !^index2\.php$ /index2.php [L,R=302]
</IfModule>

Comment: ok, changing your rewritecond to RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(_assets)/ works...(had to add the not qualifier before the carat)...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### To prevent endless looping (index2.php <--> index2.php):

Only redirect If URL to be redirected does NOT contain the string 'index2.php'

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !index2.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index2.php [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use mod_rewrite

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteCond {REQUEST_URI} !=/index2.php

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^.*$       /index2.php

    # End .HTACCESS

    </IfModule>`

Comment: sorry, forgot to exclude the file you want to serve.  I've updated it.

Comment: Thanks Eddy but I'm still getting an internal server error, any ideas as to why?

Comment: Hrm, could you add some logging eg) RewriteLogLevel 9 /path/to/logs

Answer (score 0):

I'd be more inclined to use the slightly different

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteRule ^/.*$ /index2.php [R=307,L]
</IfModule>
```

This will let you return a moved temporarily status for the redirect.

Omitting this set of flags means that mod_rewrite will return a 302 Found status by default.

HTH

cheers,

Comment: a few images and includes of header and footer information, could that be causing it?  Meaning it's trying to redirect the include files?

Comment: Oh and an fyi, I've tried the code above and now it doesn't do any redirecting at all...